# GCM send message fails with 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to publish a message to GCM. But the send call fails with 401 status. 
I am passing the Authorization header. 
Passing the correct API key (with allow any IP). 
I have Enabled the Cloud messaging service. 
I have also tried using the browser key in place of API key(with no referrer)

The curl request looks like this >

curl -v --header "Authorization:key=VALID API KEY" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"r1\"]}"

```
POST /gcm/send HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.24.0 NSS/3.13.5.0 zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2

Host: android.googleapis.com

Accept: */*

Authorization:key= VALID API KEY With allow all IP

Content-Type:application/json

Content-Length: 28
```

Nothing seems to work. Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: Solved. Created a new project enabled the GCM service and generated new API key. But still not sure on why it is not working in the old project.