# How to Troubleshoot Android GCM 401 error?

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I'm getting many `401` **Unauthorized** errors when trying to connect to Google Cloud Message Server.

Our code was working for some time on our test server but on the production one it fails some times.

The API key was working ok, the push notifications arrive (eventually), but meanwhile I get a lot of `401` errors.

I've verified on the console that **server IP address** is on the **white list**:

When following [Google Troublesooting guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error), I get surprising results:

```
me@myserver:~$ :curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFFU" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
me@myserver:~$ curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFFU" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
{"multicast_id":7560936933053964665,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
me@myserver:~$ curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFFU" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Sometimes, the same `curl` command works and sometimes it doesn't without any change nor in the console nor in the command line... As sometimes it works, I asume the key it's ok (I've double checked the key and the allowed IPs several times).

I have checked all the stackoverflow questions and tested all the suggestions, but even removing all the IPs from the white list (to allow requests from any IP) the behavior is still the same, some times it works some times it doesn't

Some references I've checked:

- [GCM with PHP (Google Cloud Messaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging)
- [GCM http 401 authorization error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521459/gcm-http-401-authorization-error)
- [Unreliable 401 errors with GCM services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063043/unreliable-401-errors-with-gcm-services)
- [GCM send message fails with 401 (Unauthorized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170009/gcm-send-message-fails-with-401-unauthorized)

Any advice on what can be going on would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many checks and not finding a good result the only solution we could give was to create a **new project** (the 3rd one because we did it already before) with a **new API key**, and this 3rd time it works.

Comment: We're having a very similar problem. Did you ever find any other information?

Comment: @JakeBraun No, after creating a new API key and trying for the rd time it worked and we stopped looking...

Comment: it's the same for me. strange

Comment: good luck @valeriocomo we really couldn't find the root cause of the problem

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem by creating new **API Key** under same project. Following this

Go to Google developer console then Select project **Credentials -> Create Credentials -> API Key -> Server Key** then add your server ip address where your GCM server code hosted.

After creating Api key it may takes 5 minutes to be workable

Answer (score 0):

It might happen that IPv6 is used for the connection while only IPv4 is allowed.
Make sure you have 'Any IP allowed' not just IPv4 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: We did that without success :(

Comment: To set 'Any IP allowed' leave the 'IPS' field blank.