# Bluemix push notification for android is not sending any notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm trying to use the sample code available here: https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-hellopush

And the first difficulty I found was on configuring the GCM - it seems that somethings changed since it was documented - anyway I guess I got everything configured correctly.

I got the app working and I'm able to register my device, but there is no notification when I try to send it. I'm using both the bluemix dashboard and the swagger to send a message. The response I get is that the message was sent, but I got nothing on the device (a mobile phone, not the emulator).

I checked my Google API dashboard, and there is no activity on the GCM api.

The application ID is: f97eb706-3375-438d-8221-cd7ac0266de1

Answer (score 3):

I was using Postman to test the GCM API (https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send) and I was getting an "Error 401 Unauthorized". I tried to create a new API Key, but without success.

After reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22453025/6828416
I tried to create a new project on GCM, and it **suddenly started to work**.

Comment: Today at a demonstration I had this problem again today @joe - can you help me trying to debug it?

Comment: Sure! If you open a support ticket, we should be able to see more info about your service instance and could potentially do a screensharing session if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The Docs are currently being updated for GCM, so that will be fixed very soon.

I attempted to recreate your problem and just tested out the sample with Push Notifications with the Android sample here (with the latest version of Android Studio v2.1.3):

**Before:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

Here is how I edited my code snippets after cloning the sample (mock values):

**Code Edit 1 Before:**

```
BMSClient.getInstance().initialize(this, "<APPLICATION_ROUTE>", "<APPLICATION_ID>", BMSClient.REGION_US_SOUTH);
```

**Code Edit 1 After:**

```
BMSClient.getInstance().initialize(this, "http://imfpush.ng.bluemix.net", "dfadsfadsfdsf-2343-2334-8e82-421c02ce847c", BMSClient.REGION_US_SOUTH);
```

**Code Edit 2 Before:**

```
push.initialize(this, "<APPLICATION_ID>", "<CLIENT_SECRET>");
```

**Code Edit 2 After:**

```
push.initialize(this, "dfadsfadsfdsf-2343-2334-8e82-421c02ce847c", "edec64df-34fd-44e3-9d1e-dfsfsdf989899");
```

I got these values from the Push Notifications service credentials (mock values).

[image: service credentials]

---

Here is how I set up GCM:

In my Bluemix config, it looks something like this (mock values):

[image: gcm credentials]

Here's how I got those values from GCM (mock values):

**Sender ID:**

[image: senderid]

**API Key:**

[image: apikey]

Comment: Please follow up with me to let me know if this works out for you. If it doesn't, we can do some more debugging.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I created everything from scratch and I still can't get notifications. ![Screenshot](http://i64.tinypic.com/1euank.jpg).

Comment: I noticed that your API Key was created on May, 3, 2016. @joe Can you please run a new test by creating a new API and a new API Key? I believe Google made some changes to the GCM, and what I get is different from yours.

Answer (score 1):

@Paulo For new projects the dashboard is not coming up to enable GCM API in https://console.developers.google.com.
Steps to enable GCM:
Create New Project->create API Key->Enable GCM.
To Enable GCM please Navigate to Dashboard tab and search for Google Cloud Messaging-> Click on GCM and enable the API. Please wait for 5 min to get it activate.

[image]

Configure the GCM credentials for Push Notification-> register the device and send notification.